# Is asking for a help in debugging a part of a code allowed on SO?

Tags: discussion, debugging-questions

Imagine I'm stuck in situation where I was not able to debug my code on my own. Am I allowed to ask for help on StackOverflow by providing the Stack Trace and relevant exception details?

Comment: Yes. But don't forget to research the problem before posting. See [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: And explain in what *way* you're not able to debug code on your own.